# Auto create objects with ForeignKey when save in Django

Tags: python, django

I got problem with Django auto create objects.Please help me.
I have a model **Avatar** that:

```
class Avatar(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='avatar_owner')
    photoset = models.ForeignKey(PhotoSet, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=avatar_file_path)
```

and model

```
class PhotoSet(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200, null=True)
```

I want to create a def when saving model Avatar with a null photoset, it will auto get_or_create a Photoset with a certain title. I made a def like this but it's not work.

```
@transaction.atomic
def create_default_photoset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.photoset is None:
        self.photoset, _ = Photoset.objects.get_or_create(title=self.id)

    super(Avatar, self).create_default_photoset(*args, **kwargs)
```

Am I wrong with this def? How can I fix that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: When do you call your method? If you call it before `save` of Avatar - the `self.id` will be None

Comment: And another consent - `super(Avatar, self).create_default_photoset` it's a call for parent class, but I don't think that Model has such method. Anyway, please explain "does not work" in more details, e.g. traceback of error

Comment: @Igor can't work. This is all def:

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id is None:
        saved_image = self.image
        self.image = None
        super(Avatar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.image = saved_image
    if self.photoset is None:
        self.photoset, _ = Photoset.objects.get_or_create(title='test')
        super(Avatar, self).create_default_photoset(*args, **kwargs)

    super(Avatar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

@Igor: This is all my code

Comment: You use `super(Avatar, self).create_default_photoset(*args, **kwargs)` that means *call method of parent class*. Try to replace it with `self.create_default_photoset(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: This is all my code Igor. Your solution is not work too.
http://collabedit.com/c2aa5. Please take a look

Comment: What is this function - `super(Avatar, self).create_default_photoset(*args, **kwargs)`. I don't know if django defines such method, but I think no. So what method do you try to call here? Also, when you say *"does not work"* - please provide either traceback, or describe actual and desired behavior